# Change filename - When export graph amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I want to change the filename while export from amcharts graph download option. Currently it was downloading with name amcharts.jpg or amcharts.pdf.

Kindly assists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the filename by setting the `fileName` property, as indicated in the [export plugin documentation](https://github.com/amcharts/export#complete-list-of-available-export-settings).

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "fileName": "your new file name without extension", 
    // ...
  }
});
```

You can also set the `fileName` at the format level through the [`menuReviver` callback](https://github.com/amcharts/export#menu-item-reviver). You can use this to override the top level `fileName` property depending on the format.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "fileName": "top level filename",
    "menuReviver": function(item, li) {
      if (item.format === "JPG") {
        item.fileName = "customJPGName"; //different file name for JPG files
      }
      return li;
    }
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pjs0tyrf/)

Answer (score 1):

create an amChart and prefix the chart with preferred file name

```
chart: any;
this.chart = am4core.create('core-chart', am4charts.XYChart);
this.chart.exporting.filePrefix = "preferred file name";
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do something like this:

```
var chart = am4core.create("Any chartname", am4charts.XYChart3D);

chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
chart.exporting.filePrefix = "The exporting file name";
```